# Change index entry in the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

I want to change how the index entry is shown in the ToC:

Right now I have the ToC like this:

[image: How it is]

I want to capitalize it:

[image: How I want]

I can do it by changing the index name, however, it messes with the index page :(

Can I customize it only in the ToC page? (like I did with the Glossary)

Code:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\addto{\captionsbrazil}{
    \renewcommand*{\indexname}{Índice Remissivo}
}
...
\printindex % printing the index
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent the automatic addition of the index to the TOC, and then instead add it manually. For example, use

```
\usepackage[intoc=false]{imakeidx}
```

instead of `\usepackage{makeidx}` in the preamble, and then, at the end of the document:

```
\phantomsection % assuming you have hyperref loaded, otherwise omit
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INDICE REMISSIVO}
\printindex
```

That should do it. (Should you be using the `tocbibind` package, pass it the `noindex` option to suppress automatic generation of the TOC entry for the index).